# Aws Ec2 ssh access - permission denied(publickey)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

Looks like I'm not the first one struggling with this one.

Until now, I had no problem accessing my EC2 instance through SSH. Till now.

Whatever I do, I get a permission denied error. I checked my ec2 user a zillion times, my security group parameters too. My IP is correctly registered in the inbound rules.

I tried using instance DNS and IP. And I forced keygen regeneration using keygen -r. Stille the same. My key pair file has the rights 0600.

This probably happened after an instance reboot (not a stop/start, from EC2 dashboard, not from shell). My instance is running without any alarms and my website is correctly  displayed.

Here comes my ssh command :

```
ssh -v -i "~/.ssh/namaste_3.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-29-237-225.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

or

```
ssh -v -i "~/.ssh/keypair.pem" ubuntu@52.29.237.225
```

Here comes my ssh -v output :

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.29.237.225 [52.29.237.225] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/brice/.ssh/namaste_3.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/brice/.ssh/namaste_3.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 52.29.237.225:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:yiGarcstgUfXZmop1URjMPa/pp1J5mak4Rsl6TWuAh4
debug1: Host '52.29.237.225' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/brice/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: bleroux@fluksaqua.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/brice/.ssh/namaste_3.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any clue ? I really don't feel like starting a new instance from scratch...

Comment: Try a test: can you ssh to another machine?
It could be something on the lines of http://askubuntu.com/questions/343060/no-more-authentication-methods-to-try-permission-denied-publickey/343217 (permissions are wrong on one of the machines)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not have another running instance. I cloned that one from the aws dashboard. Well... No problem with that one.

Comment: I still can't access my old instance and I don't get why. Took me a few hours to get on my feet... Even though this is still a beta, I'm gonna have to elevate my backup strategy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance is a EBS root instance, you can ALWAYS diagnose it by UNMOUNT the root volume from the instance, then mount it to a running EC2 instance to check whats goes wrong with the EC2 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Create a snapshot for the volume before doing any changes. After you fix it, just mount it back to the instance.

Attempt to hardened EC2 /home/ubuntu/.ssh using chmod 600 by accident always cause the problem. You need at least u+rwx for ~/.ssh folder. Because the correct ways is this.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

So, always, 700 for the folder. NOT 600.

Don't ask me why I know this ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I will try and cha ge the permissions accordingly, but I just stopped the instance and launched another one. Just cost me a few hours.

Whenever I get  to check that I'll be back to you.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove entry from known_hosts

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname/IP
```

Then change permission of Key file to 400